# Error while trying to predict on SavedModel using tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to predict on a savedmodel using the following code

```
 features = np.ones((20, 40, 3), dtype=np.float32)
 features = tf.convert_to_tensor(value, dtype=tf.float32)
 imported_model = tf.saved_model.load(export_dir=os.path.join(os.path.join(model_path, directory)))
 import_fn = imported_model.signatures["serving_default"]
 import_fn(features)
```

I get the following error when running it using Tensorflow 2. The model prediction works fine when I use the saved_model_cli.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  In[0] is not a matrix. Instead it has shape [20,40,3]
     [[node dense/BiasAdd (defined at model_manager.py:54) ]] [Op:__inference_pruned_318590]
```

The saved cli command is as follows

```
saved_model_cli run --dir ./model_dir --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default --input_exprs 'input=np.ones((20, 40, 3), dtype=np.float32)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**InvalidArgumentError** is typically caused by **Data Type mismatch** in the input.

Based on your error " *In[0] is not a matrix. Instead, it has shape [20,40,3]* ". 
You could try to manipulate your input data to **properly match** the input type and shape that the model is originally trained. You could also inspect how the model treats your input when you used the **saved_model_cli** compared to **Python IDE**. As you might be missing some preprocessing steps when you used the Python IDE that is being done when using saved_model_cli.

You could read about using **Saved_Model format** usage more in this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model).

Comment: I edited the question to include the saved_model_cli command. I actually tried it on numpy ones array of the same shape and type. I don't think it is a type issue.

Comment: Hi @VBK,  I would like to know the behavior if you remove this line of code in your Python code "**features = tf.convert_to_tensor(value, dtype=tf.float32)**". Thanks.

Comment: I get the error  All inputs to `ConcreteFunction`s must be Tensors;

Comment: Hi @VBK, I don't know if you notice but there is an error in your code snippet and I am not such whether this is intended or not. 
**features** = np.ones((20, 40, 3), dtype=np.float32)
features = tf.convert_to_tensor(**value**, dtype=tf.float32).. You seems to be passing value variable rather than the features variable.

Comment: @VBK Also I would like to ask for you to include the result of "saved_model_cli show --dir 
/tmp/saved_model_dir --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default". For us to troubleshoot your problem much easier.

Comment: I was doing this in a loop and it turned out to be a way I was calling this through a closure. It was getting the wrong features, model pair. But thank you so much and sorry for the trouble. I reverted tensorflow version and the error message of shape mismatch was much clearer which was how I caught it. Not sure why that was changed in 2.0.